# Text in button is vertically centered in browser but not on iPhone

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code for my button and the text is perfectly centered vertically in all browsers on my computer but in Safari on my iPhone the text seems to be 1 pixel too high up. E.g. there is more space below than above the text. Why is that?

Hopefully this will translate with the codesnippet below.

// Edit, I just tried this and in Safari and Chrome it's perfectly centered. In Firefox there is more space below and on the iPhone there is more space above. Do I have to treat them differently or is there one solution that will look good for all?

This is the default look in Firefox:
[image]
The iPhone is similar but more space at the top instead.

```css
a {
  padding: 0px 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #459e00;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: browser to browser the css may be interpreted slightly differently to actually format the element on the page.

Comment: Try `transform: translateY(-50%); top: 50%`;

Comment: @Dohab Just did. Same result.

Comment: `top:` isn't going to do anything if the element isn't absolutely positioned somehow, even be it relative. The code you've given doesn't even center vertically on desktop.

Comment: @Laif For me it does in Safari and Chrome. I just removed the transform code again. Or maybe there is slightly more space below in Safari and Chrome on a second look. Made it caps to make it easier to see.

Comment: @Laif you're right. position should be `absolute`, Only when `<a>` is placed inside `<div>` which is `relative` position.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've given that will position it vertically in any way.

Comment: @Laif True, I was just hoping (assuming) that the text would be centered if I don't alter it in any way. Seems like a logical default position.

Comment: @SeaBass I don't think I understand, are you talking about the text _inside_ the button or the button itself?

Comment: @Laif I'm talking about the text

Answer (score 0):

to style anchor content, place an anchor around a style-able element like `div`.

```css
a {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #459e00;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

a > div{
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%); top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div>Button</div></a>
```

---

You could also give `<a>` `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to achieve something similar without the divs, but this is generally unconventional and not recommended.

```css
a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #459e00;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">Button</a>
```

Comment: Really, I can't just center it in the `<a>` itself? Will it work if I change it to a button, div, span or input element instead of a?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. anchor isn't a display element, it just tells it's content to act like a link.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't you move all the display css to the div?

Comment: You could, the difference here is that div is a block-type element, I'm going to add an  edit to show how you could accomplish the same with an `<a>`

Comment: Updated, let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Ok thanks, afraid I can't do table-cell. No other element type that takes `vertical-align: middle;`?

Comment: [Read more about it here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of flexbox, that ought to solve your issue by aligning and justifying the contents of your button vertically and horizontally respectively.

Flexbox should cover all of the browsers you mentioned above: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
a {
    padding: 0px 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #459e00;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   }
```

```html
<a href="#">BUTTON</a>
```